# Creating Multiple buttons on a Home page. Very new to this and dont know much. SignUp button results in the "application stopping"

Tags: java, android, xml

```
package com.example.james.assignment1_18094969;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {


    //login button
    Button loginButton;
    //sign up button
    Button signupButton;
enter code here

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

login button to take the user to the login screen, this button works fine.

```
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    );
```

signUp button to take the user to the signUp form activity this results in 'Application has stopped working' even though it is the exact same... confused. enter code here

```
        signupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_signUp);

        signupButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, SignUp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

}

    }
```

Log:

```
01-06 13:27:42.934 2417-2417/com.example.james.assignment1_18094969 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.james.assignment1_18094969, PID: 2417
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.james.assignment1_18094969/com.example.james.assignment1_18094969.SignUp}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.james.assignment1_18094969.SignUp.onCreate(SignUp.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context="com.example.james.assignment1_18094969.Home">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/speedy"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Delivery"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button_delivery"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:text="Pick Up"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_delivery"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_delivery"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_delivery"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:id="@+id/button_pickUp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Quick Order"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_pickUp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_pickUp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_pickUp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:id="@+id/button_quickOrd"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/red"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to Speedy Pizza!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="@color/red"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_signUp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: dumb question but how? new to this

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: The code in the question is fine, the problem is in SignUp.java. Show the onCreate() method of SignUp.java.

Comment: @james make sure that you declared in manifest

Comment: @james.d_12 this error is happened due to the missing of  button id in the SignUp class and if you post the SignUp class its very easy to find out...

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your log, the app can't find the `button_signUp` view and is throwing an exception because of this. Best to check if the `button_signUp` id matches the id used in your XML.

Note: [findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) returns null if the view isn't found

For more info on NullPointerException see [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: the id matches and isn't in red within the java or anything.